# Java compile in Sublime Text 3

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I'm trying to compile java in Sublime text 3. I have made PATH to Java bin and made a build file, but I get this on the first compile in Sublime terminal and nothing changes after subsequent compiles. I got C to compile but can't figure java.

```
str expected, not list
    [cmd: ['javac', 'hello.java', '&&', 'java', 'hello']]
    [dir: C:\code\java\second]
    [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;"C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;";"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;"C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\cygwin64\bin";C:\Users\Rudolfs\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Rudolfs\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Rudolfs\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;]
    [Finished]
```

Comment: are you compiling using ctrl + b?

Comment: Is that the full output in the build results panel? Also if you can include the `sublime-build` file you created as well we may have a better idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` there is a bashism; you aren't running bash, you are running direct process access. It's as if you pass `&&` directly to the javac process and javac has no idea what to do with it.

Check if sublime text has the ability to run 2 things in sequence (preferably not running the second thing if the first failed). If not, make a bash script and run that.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are building your system in java.
- Make sure that you have saved you script file with .java extension
- Make a new build and change the script in it to

  {
  "shell_cmd": "javac $file && java $file_base_name"
  }

Now go back to build and build it by using RunJava
If you are still facing errors, it could be due to syntax errors so for that provide use with the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) by Package Control: `Package Control: install` > `Terminus`.
2. Create new Build Systems `Tools > Build Systems > New Build System`
3. Type in file next:

```js
{
"target": "terminus_exec",
"cancel": "terminus_cancel_build",
"shell_cmd": "javac $file_name && java $file_base_name",
"working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

4. And save this file as `RunJava.sublime-build` for example.
5. Select created Build System `Tools > Build Systems > RunJava`
6. Then run your code by `Tools > Build`

P.S. If you have input, type it in console and press Enter.
It works on Windows 11.